# TypeError: Database is not a constructor when initializing constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Database object (database.js) that looks like this:

```
//create the database 
function Database(host, dbuser, dbpassword){
    this.host = host;
    this.dbuser = dbuser;
    this.dbpassword = dbpassword;
    this.connection = null;
}

Database.prototype = {
    connection: function(){
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: host,
            user: dbuser
        });
    },
    createDatabase: function(){...};
```

I'm then importing this object into my main app.js using a require statement

```
var db = require('./database.js');
```

However, when I try to construct my database object, I get a TypeError Database is not a constructor

```
var connection = new db('localhost','root');
connection.connection();
```

What am I doing wrong here? I read up on prototypes and it seems that I'm not lacking anything in that department so it seems that it has something to do with my require statement?

Comment: Because node.js support ES6 by default now, use `class`. It will makes your code easier and you gonna avoid errors like this.

Comment: But is there any reason this prototype wont work? I'd have to read up on classes but I thought prototypes were still supported...

Comment: How did you exported `Database` in your file `database.js`?

Comment: I did _exports.Database = Database;_

Comment: `{host: host, user: dbuser}` → `{host: this.host, user: this.dbuser}`

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that. Updated my code and it's still spitting out the TypeError at the line where I initialize the Database object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export your `Database` `"class"` use

`module.exports = Database;`

And to use

```
var Database = require('./database.js');

new Database(...);
```

---

[Here you have a good tutorial about how to use export/require](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/)

---

**Is still strongly recommend to upgrade to ES6.**

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! Worked perfectly! Still iffy on the workings on Node but this seemed to fix my problem