# SQLite3 Database is not a constructor

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sqlite, discord.js

So in my project I am trying to gather simple Discord username and unique identifier from discord and store it in SQLite database file. I get the error:

` let userDB = new sqlite.Database('./disco.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE);
^

TypeError: sqlite.Database is not a constructor`

Here is my code in my index.js

```
// Requirements
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const ServList = client.guilds.cache.size;
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
require('dotenv').config()

//client login function
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);


// Start up Check list
client.once('ready', () => {
    //Log and Set Status
    console.log('Bot Online');
    client.user.setActivity(`Proudly in ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`, {
     type: "WATCHING",
    }, 60000);
    
    //Database Initialization
    let userDB = new sqlite.Database('./disco.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite.OPEN_CREATE);

});
```

Here is my code for the command that is creating the error:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();

module.exports = {
    name: 'create',
    description: "Create your account!",
    use(message, args, client, sqlite){
    
    // Data to Add
    let userDB = new sqlite.Database('./disco.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE);
    userDB.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST usersInfo(userID INTEGER NOT NULL, uNameR TEXT NOT NULL)`);

    let userID = message.author.id;
    let uName = message.author.tag;
    let uQuery = `SELECT * FROM usersInfo WHERE userID = ?`;

    userDB.get(uQuery, [userID], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        if (row === undefined){
            userDB.prepare(`INSERT INTO usersInfo VALUES(?,?)`);
            insertdata.run('userID, uName');
            insertdata.finalize();
            userDB.close();
        } else {
            let userID2 = row.userID;
            let yName = row.uNameR;
            console.log(yName, userID);
        }
    
    });

    message.channel.send('success');
    }

}
```

Edit: Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question. If the answers there do not address your problem, please edit to explain in detail the parts of your question that are unique.

The suggestion solution does not work for me as the suggested answer utilizes mySQL while I use SQLite3, Not only that but the suggested answer attempts to connect to a hosted database while mine is local.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Database is not a constructor when initializing constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409129/typeerror-database-is-not-a-constructor-when-initializing-constructor)

Comment: That did not solve my issue, They are using mySQL I am using SQLite3

Answer (score 0):

The verbose method when loading the module is causing the problem.

```
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
```

Try temporarily removing it from the require and your code should run properly. If your running into this problem, try adding verbose to the individual database code statements instead of loading it with the module.